# Call instance method inside function called from .call()

Tags: typescript, n8n

I'm writing a n8n node which is basically a function that runs every time something happens.

I created an abstract class that is called by n8n environment, but it's not possible to call its methods as n8n calls functions using `Class.execute.call(thisArgs)` which overrides `this` context for class instance.

#### How n8n lib calls my class

I copied this code from n8n source code

```js
import { createContext, Script } from 'vm'
import { AbstractNode } from './n8n'

const context = createContext({ require })
export const loadClassInIsolation = <T>(filePath: string, className: string) => {
  const script = new Script(`new (require('${filePath}').${className})()`)
  return script.runInContext(context) as T
}

async function run(): Promise<void> {
  const myClass = loadClassInIsolation<AbstractNode<unknown>>(
    '../dist/codex/node/Codex.node.js',
    'Codex',
  )
  const thisArgs = {
    prepareOutputData: (d: any): any => ({ ...d }),
  }
  console.log(await myClass.execute.call(thisArgs, thisArgs))
}

void run()
```

#### My abstract class

This is the class that I'm having issue using `this`

```js
import { IExecuteFunctions, INodeExecutionData, INodeType } from 'n8n-workflow'

export abstract class AbstractNode<TParams> implements Omit<INodeType, 'description'> {
  private _executeFunctions: IExecuteFunctions = null

  set executeFunctions(value: IExecuteFunctions) {
    this._executeFunctions = value
  }

  get executeFunctions(): IExecuteFunctions {
    return this._executeFunctions
  }

  abstract run(t: TParams): Promise<INodeExecutionData>

  async execute(): Promise<INodeExecutionData[][]> {
    this.executeFunctions = this as unknown as IExecuteFunctions

    // THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK
    // ERROR: TypeError: this.run is not a function
    await this.run({ prompts: ['hello', 'world'] } as TParams)

    return this.executeFunctions.prepareOutputData([
      { json: { answer: 'Sample answer' } },
    ])
  }
}
```

#### Class dynamically instantiated

This class implements abstract `run` method in AbstractNode

```js
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common'
import { FirefliesContext } from '@src/common'
import { AbstractNode } from '@src/n8n'
import { INodeExecutionData } from 'n8n-workflow'

type CodexParams = { prompts: string[] }

export class Codex extends AbstractNode<CodexParams> {
  run({ prompts }: CodexParams): Promise<INodeExecutionData> {
    console.log(`Prompts="${prompts.join(', ')}"`)
  }
}
```

#### What I've tried

The reason of this error is that `.call(thisArgs)` overrides this context inside `execute` function, one possible solution is to change `execute` to arrow function, but when I do that I don't have access to `thisArgs`.

My question is: Is there any way to have access to class instance `this` and `thisArgs` from `.call()`? With both I can call implemented abstract method and use helpers functions from `thisArgs`

Comment: In source code n8n doesn't do just `.call(thisArgs)`, but `.call(thisArgs, thisArgs)`. Can you change `execute` to arrow function and get `thisArgs` not through `this` but through its first argument?

Comment: Just tried getting args `execute = async(...args: any[]) => {}` it returns an empty array. I see [this](https://github.com/n8n-io/n8n/blob/03afd3c7cf80e89f1195b1e54746b3335dc9f3d8/packages/workflow/src/Workflow.ts#L1270) and it's not passing the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic quick albeit a bit dirty way is to define this function inside of the constructor, where you have access to both `this` values

```
export abstract class AbstractNode<TParams> implements Omit<INodeType, 'description'> {
  execute: () => Promise<INodeExecutionData[][]>

  constructor() {
    const self = this
    this.execute = async function(this: IExecuteFunctions) {
      self.executeFunctions = this
      await self.run({ prompts: ['hello', 'world'] } as TParams)
  
      return self.executeFunctions.prepareOutputData([
        { json: { answer: 'Sample answer' } },
      ])
    }
  }
}
```

Also when you define a class field, `this` is always available and you can do something weird like this if you don't want the constructor to get cluttered:

```
export abstract class AbstractNode<TParams> implements Omit<INodeType, 'description'> {
  execute = ((self) => async function (this: IExecuteFunctions) Promise<INodeExecutionData[][]> {
    self.executeFunctions = this
    await self.run({ prompts: ['hello', 'world'] } as TParams)

    return self.executeFunctions.prepareOutputData([
      { json: { answer: 'Sample answer' } },
    ])
  })(this)
}
```

Or move it to [helper function](https://tsplay.dev/mq98Zm) to make it more readable

```
const withCallContextAsArgument = <
  TCallContext,
  TArgs extends any[], 
  TReturnType
>(
  // Adding "this: null" for safety, so that you have to pass an arrow function when using
  // this helper and no "this" weirdness can occur
  f: (this: null, callContext: TCallContext, ...args: TArgs) => TReturnType
) => function(this: TCallContext, ...args: TArgs) {
    return f.call(null, this, ...args)
}

export abstract class AbstractNode<TParams> implements Omit<INodeType, 'description'> {
  executeFunctions!: IExecuteFunctions
  abstract run(arg: any): Promise<void>

  execute = withCallContextAsArgument(async (thisArgs: IExecuteFunctions): Promise<INodeExecutionData[][]> => {
    this.executeFunctions = thisArgs
    await this.run({ prompts: ['hello', 'world'] } as TParams)

    return this.executeFunctions.prepareOutputData([
      { json: { answer: 'Sample answer' } },
    ])
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, it does the job! I'll move on with your solution, I opened a [PR](https://github.com/n8n-io/n8n/pull/5388) to change from `execute.call(thisArgs)` to `execute.call(thisArgs, thisArgs)`

Comment: Nice! I also realised that in the helper function solution you don't need to pass `this` as argument when using arrow function, so I updated that solution to be less weird

Comment: The evolution of the JavaScript ecosystem:

1. Prototypal inheritance is too confusing.  Let's import Java as a precompiler and call it TypeScript.
2. Class semantics are too restrictive.  Let's use `.call` to override `this` and send an arbitrary TypeScript interface as a payload.
3. Unit testing is too hard.  Just run the service and test from the UI.